# How to add two char arrays and get the output as a char array

Tags: java, arrays

I want to concat two char arrays:

```
char[] vowels1 = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'}; 
char[] vowels2 = {'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'};
```

and get the output as `[a, e, i, o, u, A, E, I, O, U]`.

How can I do this in Java?

Comment: Seems like a simple problem. What have you tried on your own? Did you do any research? If you did, please mention the problem that you are facing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `System.arraycopy()` method to copy `vowels1` and `vowels2` content to `vowels3`.
It's signature is as follows:
`arraycopy(Object src, int srcPos, Object dest, int destPos, int length)`
Where:
**src** denotes the source array.
**srcPos** is the index from which copying starts.
**dest** denotes the destination array.
**destPos** is the index from which the copied elements are placed in the the destination array.
**length** is the length of the subarray to be copied.

```
        char[] vowels1={'a','e','i','o','u'};
        char[] vowels2={'A','E','I','O','U'};
        
        char[] vowels3 = new char[vowels1.length + vowels2.length];
        System.arraycopy(vowels1 , 0, vowels3, 0, vowels1.length);
        System.arraycopy(vowels2 , 0, vowels3, vowels1.length, vowels2.length);
        
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(vowels3));
```

**Output:**
`[a, e, i, o, u, A, E, I, O, U]`

Answer (score 0):

You could convert them to strings, concatenate those strings and convert it back to an array. Not the most performant option, mind you, but very little code required:

```
char[] vowels = (new String(vowels1)+new String(vowels2)).toCharArray();
```